# Provide \degree symbol in MathJax

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

A while ago I posted [an answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19678/35416) to the MathJax tutorial meta question about the right way to write a degree symbol. The [latest edit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/19678/6) (with which I'm not really happy) discusses, among other things, the absence of a `\degree` symbol in MathJax. But as far as I understand [the docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros), it should be fairly easy to provide a macro of that name for the whole site, with whatever implementation you consider most appropriate. Benefits:

1. Would express intended meaning in the math markup, for the sake of editors.
2. Might also emit that name to screen readers, I believe. Warrants testing.
3. Does not depend on weird ways for entering <kbd>°</kbd> on keyboards that don't support it.
4. Implementation can pick whatever TeX notation renders best in a given MathJax version.

Currently suggested implementations include `°`, `^\circ` and `^\text{o}`. Semantically I prefer the first, but I get the impression that I'm in a minority here, and with this definition my main concern about doing the semantically right thing in the post itself would still be addressed.

Comment: Regarding screen readers: I tried out ChromeVox on the linked answer to the MathJax tutorial question, and it successfully read $45^\circ$ (that is, `45^\circ`) as "45 degrees". I think less intelligent screen readers that don't catch this won't do any better with a `\degree` command that unpacks to `^\circ`, since [apparently](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/accessibility-features.html) they try to read the underlying MathML, which will look like `<msup><mn>45</mn><mo>&#x2218;<!-- ∘ --></mo></msup>` either way.

Comment: The circle in $45^\circ$ looks small.  So perhaps $45^\mathrm{o}$ is better.